# What are ways to use underscore.js with global variables?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a program that reads an array of list items. It transforms the array and assigns an explicit listItem Type to each item by using the global variable listItemTypeMap to map the appropriate type. I decided for clarity this should use _.map instead of my own looping logic.

Yet when the code uses map and tries to access listItemTypeMap that variable is now undefined. When I use my own for loop it's perfectly fine. Which leads me to believe there is some kind of scoping issue when using underscore.js. I'm very new to the framework but is there anyway to circumvent or insert the global variable in a _.map object? Or do I have to rewrite how the entire class works?

```
//One part of the class
     var myNewArray= _.map(infoList, this.ReconcileListTypes);

//Another part of the class 
    MyProject.MyListManager.ReconcileListTypes = function (listItem)
        {

            var listItemCopy = null;

            if (listItem.Value == undefined)
            {                    //listItemTypeMap is undefined
            listItemCopy = _.extend({ "$type": this.listItemTypeMap[listItem.listItemType] }, listItem);

            if (listItemCopy.listItemType == listItemType.Exception)
            {
                if (listItemCopy.Base != null)
                {
                    listItemCopy.Base = _.extend({ "$type": this.listItemTypeMap[listItemCopy.Base.listItemType] }, listItemCopy.Base);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listItemCopy = _.extend({ "$type": this.listItemTypeMap[listItem.Value.listItemType] }, listItem.Value);

            if (listItemCopy.listItemType == listItemType.Exception)
            {
                if (listItemCopy.Base != null)
                {
                    listItemCopy.Base = _.extend({ "$type": this.listItemTypeMap[listItemCopy.Base.listItemType] }, listItemCopy.Base);
                }
            }
        }

    return listItemCopy;
};
```

Comment: You're introducing a new function scope when you call `_.extend()`.  The value of `this` in that scope is not the same as it was outside it -- your `ReconcileListTypes` constructor function (or is that just a method on `MyListManager`?)  In any case, you can store a reference to it before calling `_.extend`, say, `var me = this;` and then use `me` inside the `_.extend` calls.  (You should probably use a more descriptive name than `me` or `self`, but I don't understand enough to suggest one.)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. It would've taken me forever to figure it out without your nudge. What the real issue was the this even in the scope in the ReconfileListType (just a method) the 'This' was completely different because of _.map function. I'm not quite sure what scope it was but it didn't have any of the private methods of the base class that this all belongs to. So I just made 'this' a global variable that can be called no matter the scope. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad you found it; I missed the `map` call.  Two suggestions:  First, you should probably stick to the very strong JS convention of reserving initial uppercase exclusively for constructor functions.   Second, be very, very wary of global variables.  If you can store your reference in a smaller scope, you'll probably thank yourself later.

Comment: Yeah I don't like using global variables either because they can really lead to a lot of issues. Unfortunately ReconcileListTypes gets called by a lot of functions in the same class so it's the easiest solution.I do wanna rework the code so that's not the case I just can't figure out how i would pass 'this' to that function via the map call.. is that even possible?

Comment: You _could_ change the `thisObject` with `_.map.call(this, infoList, this.ReconcileListTypes)`.  (There's a similar construct with `apply`.)  I've just looked back and realized how far off-base my original comment was.  Amazing that it helped at all.  Yes, `_.extend` does create a new function context, but your `this` was resolved before that came into play.